# Пропадают картинки в slick slide при адаптиве

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, слайдер, slider-slick.js

Добрый вечер проблема следуйщая, при респонсиве слайдера пропадают его картинки.

```js
$(function(){

    $('.slider__inner-additional').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      centerMode: false,
      variableWidth: true,
      arrows: false,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 960,
      settings: { 
              
      }
    },
    ]
    });

});
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
 background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
}

ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
}

a {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.slider__inner-additional {
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.slider-additional__item {
 background-color: #e8603c;
 background-position: top center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 max-width: 140px;
 min-height: 120px;
}

.slider__inner-additional .slick-slide {
 width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="wrap">
      
  <section class="slider">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="slider__inner">

        

      <div class="slider__inner-additional">

        <div class="slider-additional__item" style="background-image: url(images/sliders/slider-additional/img-1.jpg)" >
        </div>  

        <div class="slider-additional__item" style="background-image: url(images/sliders/slider-additional/img-2.jpg)">
        </div>  

        <div class="slider-additional__item" style="background-image: url(images/sliders/slider-additional/img-3.jpg)">
        </div>  

        <div class="slider-additional__item" style="background-image: url(images/sliders/slider-additional/img-4.jpg)">
        </div>  

        <div class="slider-additional__item" style="background-image: url(images/sliders/slider-additional/img-5.jpg)">
        </div>  

        <div class="slider-additional__item" style="background-image: url(images/sliders/slider-additional/img-6.jpg)"> 
        </div>
        <div class="slider-additional__item" style="background-image: url(images/sliders/slider-additional/img-6.jpg)"> 
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Так вот без адаптива картинки отображаются нормально, но стоит только перейти черту респонсива, они сразу пропадают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте пример, который бы воспроизводил проблему.